# How to add relative path to DB file for C#

Tags: c#, ms-access, installation, special-folders

I have a C# project and I have added a Access file (`.mdb`) by `New Data Source` option.

So a copy of it is always in my project folder. Now my connection string uses that path (*C:\Users\PC\Visual Studio\Projects....*). If I'm moving the project to another directory or machine I have to manually change the path. But if I'm making the app as installable, this might not be possible.

How to make the db path relative to the project?

Comment: Did you try to use relative path: e.g. ".\Data\MyDatabase.mdb"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When configuring your installer, you specify which folder the `.mdb` file will go to. You might choose to put it in the same folder as your application's `.exe` file, or in the application's folder under `AppData`, or in the user's home folder, or any other place you like.  Just as you specify this to the installer, you can specify it in your code using the [`Environment.SpecialFolder`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) enumeration.

The problem is that during development, your `.mdb` file is usually in the root of your project folder, which coincides with none of the above.

What I do is that first of all, in project options I make sure that when my application launches during development, it always launches in the root folder of my project, not in the `./bin/Debug` folder.

Then, each time my application launches, I check whether my `.mdb` file is in the current directory of the application, and if it is, then this must be a development run, so I use it.

Otherwise, this must be a deployment run, so I use the `SpecialFolder` enum to get the folder where the `.mdb` file ought to have been placed by the installer.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use: `System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location);`

You can see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1222190/what-is-the-best-way-to-get-the-executing-exes-path-in-net) for reference.