# C# Method that restarts Main()

Tags: c#, loops, program-entry-point

I have a C# method, if a condition is not met I want to re-run the Main() method.
There are a few posts saying use loops to do this. GoTo would also work - but don't use it. Or restart the application.

No one has given a clear newbie-level explanation about the loops.

C# example:

```
public static void Method3(int userChoice){
 if(userChoice == 1){
  Console.WriteLine("do this");
 }
 else{
  Main(); // How to run the main program again from the start ?
 }
}

public static void Main(string[] args)
{
 Method1();
 int userChoice = Method2();
 Method3(userChoice);  // I want Method3 to go back to Method1() if the else statement is met.
}
```

In python this is real easy - you just call Main() from the function.

Comment: You need to give a clear newbie-level explanation of what you are trying to accomplish, because calling `Main()` from `Main` will probably not do whatever you are thinking of.

Comment: Maybe instead of calling method3 just check if userChoice is not 1 in the main method and loop the 1-2 lines above that.

Comment: In python if you did that, you would eventually encounter a stack overflow if you went back to Main too many times.

Comment: It is possible to do something that works like you expect, using tasks. I am not writing it, because it is unnecessary overhead, I do not advise it as a solution for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have `Method3()` return a `bool` so the `Main()` method knows whether to try again.

```
public static bool Method3(int userChoice)
{
    if (userChoice == 1)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("do this");
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    bool tryAgain;
    do
    {
        Method1();
        int userChoice = Method2();
        tryAgain = Method3(userChoice);
    } while (tryAgain);       
}
```

Simply calling `Main()` again instead of looping is another approach, but has some disadvantages.

- You'll have to come up with the `args` argument somehow. Maybe it's just an empty array in your case.
- It's a recursive call and affects the stack trace. After so many recursive calls, your application will crash.
- It decreases maintainability. You'll have to remember in the future if you want to add anything to the top of the `Main()` method that you're calling it from somewhere. It lends itself to the introduction of potentially hard-to-diagnose bugs. Using the loop approach encapsulates the behavior. From just looking at `Main()`, it's obvious that `Method3()` might cause another loop.

Comment: The 3rd bullet is the most important. I'm not sure why I saved it for last. It might be okay for a trivial application like you've shown, but the unexpected recursive call is a 100% unacceptable design where I work. Maintainers would flog a developer for such an approach.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, yes, you can call `Main`. Please note that in your example you are missing the `args` parameters (which would have the command line arguments). Besides that, also know that `Main` returns, and then execution continues after where you called it. Also, you would very likely end up with a stack overflow. *If I recall correctly modern versions of the JIT can optimize tail recursion, yet I do not believe they do for this particular case.*

---

About that newbie-level explanation of a loop... this is an infinite loop, it will run forever:

```
while(true)
{
    // ...
}
```

You can exit the loop with `break`

```
while(true)
{
    // ...
    if (something)
    {
        break;
    }
    // ...
}
```

Or you can change that `true` for a conditional:

```
while(!something)
{
    // ...
}
```

The idea would be to wrap `Main` in a loop, so that it would continue to run until a condition is met. You could have another method and call it in the loop, for example:

```
public static bool Execute()
{
    if (something)
    {
        // do whatever
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    while (!Execute())
    {
        // Empty
    }
}
```

There are, of course, other kinds of loops aside from the [while loop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/while), they are the [do...while loop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/do), [for loop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/for), and [foreach loop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/foreach-in).

---

Goto would work? Arguably. The idea is that you can use goto to control the flow of execution to back in the method. That is:

```
label:
// ...
goto label;
```

The above code is an infinite loop. You can, of course, introduce a condition:

```
label:
// ...
if (!something)
{
    goto label;
}
// ...
```

The while can do – sometimes with the help of a variable – whatever you can do with goto, and it is usually easier to read and less error prone.

---

Restarting the process is a bit more tricky, you need to use [Process.Start](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.start?view=netframework-4.8) to run your own executable. See [What is the best way to get the executing exe's path in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1222190/what-is-the-best-way-to-get-the-executing-exes-path-in-net).

Answer (score 0):

So it's not really hard to do but you can just use a while loop.

C#:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
     while(true)
     {
          Method1();
          int userChoice = Method2();
          Method3(userChoice);
     }
}
```

That would give you what you want and if you want to exit you just put

```
break;
```

Comment: How is OP supposed to know if they want to exit if the logic for that is in `Method3()` and it doesn't return a value?